# Checking if a node belongs to a tree lisp

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

I have to check if a node belongs to a tree in lisp and I don't know why it isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
(defun number-of-elems (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) 0)
    (t (1+ (number-of-elems (cdr l))))))


(defun ver (tree e)
  (setq message1 "The node belongs to the tree.")
  (setq message2 "The node does not belong to the tree.")
  (cond
    ((null tree) nil)
    ((= (number-of-elems tree) 1)
     (cond
       ((= (car tree) e) (princ message1))
       (t (princ message2))))
    ((> (number-of-elems tree) 1)
     (cond
       ((listp (car tree)) (ver (car tree) e))            
       ((atom (car tree)) 
        (cond
          ((equal (car tree) e) (princ message1))
          (t (ver (cdr tree) e))))
       ((number (car tree)) 
        (cond
          ((= (car tree) e) (princ message1))
          (t (ver (cdr tree) e))))
       (t (mapcar #'ver (cdr tree) e))))))
```

and here's an exemple of how it's supposed to work:

Tree is `(a (b (c)) (d) (e (f)))` and the node is `b` => true (I wanted to print a message instead of true or false)

Comment: If I run it like this (ver '(1 2 (3 (4))) 4), it gives me an error : In = of ((3 (4)) 4) arguments should be of type NUMBER.

Answer (score 3):

#### Not a number

> = of ((3 (4)) 4) arguments should be of type NUMBER

The error comes from `(= (car tree) e)`, because you assume that if `tree` has only one element, then this element is necessarily a number. Here, the `car` of the singleton is itself a list, which makes `=` fail.

#### Don't mix everything in one place

> I wanted to print a message instead of true or false

Define *another* function which calls the first one, which returns T or NIL, or you won't be able to reuse your code.
Moreover, `(setq message1)` is not what you would want here, since it modifies the global binding of the `message1` symbol. One would use [`let`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm), but *here* you don't need it if you just do `(princ (if (ver ...) "Ok" "Not found"))`.

#### Stop iterating that list

You keep counting elements in your lists with `number-of-elems` (see also [`length`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_length.htm)). If you perform a linear operation for each element, you'll have a quadratic time complexity. In order to visit a tree, you only want to differentiate from empty and non-empty lists. The case with length equal to 1 is already supported by the general case.

#### Remove dead code

`(number (car tree))` should probably be `(numberp (car tree))` (notice the **p**). But more importantly, the code associated with this clause is dead code: if you have a number, it is an atom and the previous clause matches. Also, testing with `equal` also works with numbers.

Likewise, I don't see how to reach the default clause `(T (mapcar ...))`. This is somewhat a good news, because here `mapcar` will apply `#'ver` on each pair `(x,y)` of elements, where `x` is taken from `(cdr tree)` and `y` from `e` ! And the result is a list! Since you are looking for a match, you could use [`some`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_everyc.htm) instead, but you already could cover the case in the `listp` clause.
- `(listp (car tree))` If your first element is a list, you call the function recursively with that list, but what about `(cdr tree)`? Either the element is found in `(car tree)`, *or* it is not found and you should try with the remaining elements.

#### A hint

Here is the trace of execution for what you want:

```
    0: (ver (1 2 (3 (4))) 4)
      1: (ver 1 4)
      1: ver returned nil
      1: (ver 2 4)
      1: ver returned nil
      1: (ver (3 (4)) 4)
        2: (ver 3 4)
        2: ver returned nil
        2: (ver (4) 4)
          3: (ver 4 4)
          3: ver returned t
        2: ver returned t
      1: ver returned t
    0: ver returned t
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with the Scheme dialect of Lisp, in which the `member` function would be written:

```
(define (member? tree e)
  (if (not (pair? tree))
      (equal? tree e)
      (or (member? (car tree) e)
          (member? (cdr tree) e))))
```

In Common Lisp it should be:

```
(defun tree-member (tree e)
  (if (atom tree) ; alternatively: (not (consp tree))
      (equal tree e)
      (or (tree-member (car tree) e)
          (tree-member (cdr tree) e))))
```

You might consider making the equality predicate another argument with a default value.

Comment: ^ `; alternatively: (not (consp tree))` — `atom` is historically strange in lacking the `-p`, but `cons` v. `consp` is significant (construct a pair v. test wether it is a constructed pair)

Comment: Also … `member` is an existing function in the `CL` package, so you'd need to pick a new name. Maybe `tree-contains-p`?

Comment: @BRPocock, thanks I've incorporated your corrections

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem is I have to use cond, not if, so I tried a different approach:(defun veri (tree e)
  (cond
      ((null tree) nil)
      ((listp (car tree)) (or (veri (car tree) e) (veri (cdr tree) e)))
      ((equal (car tree) e) T)     
      (t (veri (cdr tree) e))
   ) 
)  This works fine but only if nodes are numbers. Also I have to use mapcar.